# How to use openpyxl to add 3 Arrows iconset to Excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to add 3 arrow iconset to a cell if：

(1) cell value > 0, show up direction arrow;

(2) cell value < 0, show down direction arrow;

(3) cell value = 0, show right direction arrow.

(Please see the attached images.)

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import IconSetRule

workbook = load_workbook(filename="sample.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.active

icon_set_rule = IconSetRule("3Arrows", "num", [0, 0, 0])
sheet.conditional_formatting.add("A2:A25", icon_set_rule)
workbook.save("sample.xlsx")
```

But it did not work the way I want, because Excel calculates 67% and 33% of all values in column A2 to A25.

**Excel sheet after run the python code**

[image: Excel sheet after run the python code]

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need to create three separate rules. The predefined rulesets are pretty inflexible.

Comment: Thanks Charlie. The problem is that Excel calculates 67% and 33% positions, our position is 0, even with 3 separate rules, I cannot use 0.

Comment: -1 get a red arrow, but anything less than -1 get nothing. I could not figure out how Excel(or Python) get -1 to assign a red arrow.

Comment: Brain-stormed by Charlie Clark, seems I get it:

from openpyxl.formatting.rule import IconSet, FormatObject
first = FormatObject(type='num', val=-50)
second = FormatObject(type='num', val=0)
third = FormatObject(type='num', val=1)
iconset = IconSet(iconSet='3Arrows', cfvo=[first, second, third], showValue=None, percent=None, reverse=None)
# assign the icon set to a rule
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
rule = Rule(type='iconSet', iconSet=iconset)

sheet.conditional_formatting.add("A2:A25", rule)

But I donot know why it's -50, 0 and 1, just by test

Comment: Note to my previous:

3 intervals: [ -50, 0], [0, 1], [1, infinite]

interesting is: -50 is the value we need to pay attention, less than -50, no arrow. So, if it's -10, then -11 has nothing

Comment: ```python

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import IconSetRule
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import IconSet, FormatObject

first = FormatObject(type='num', val=-50)
second = FormatObject(type='num', val=0)
third = FormatObject(type='num', val=1)

iconset = IconSet(iconSet='3Arrows', cfvo=[first, second, third], showValue=None, percent=None, reverse=None)

from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
rule = Rule(type='iconSet', iconSet=iconset)

sheet.conditional_formatting.add("H2:H250", rule)

workbook.save("sample.xlsx")

```

Comment: You should update your question with the code rather than including it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I did try few times to do that way, but it did not show that way.